# How to get the execution result of Uniswap Universal Router?

Tags: uniswap

From the sol code and doc, I didn't see any return value, so how do I get return result of a trade, for example, V3_SWAP_EXACT_IN.

Do I have to query the erc20 balanceof before and after the transaction? Or there is any other way